# How to get browser UserAgent string from iOS 8 onwards?

Tags: ios, ios8, user-agent, wkwebview

Is there any other ways to get iOS browser UserAgent string other than using the following methodology? Please help.

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<html></html>" baseURL:nil];

[webView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id __nullable userAgent, NSError * __nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", userAgent);
}];
```

Comment: your method of getting the userAgent is the best way we've come up with, @arango_86 .  we definitely do not try to match the UIWebView user-agent with the WKWebView user-agent.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
NSString *userAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
```

Comment: Hi @Renandus , I am planning  to use "WKWebView". But the way seems to be a hack. Not a standard one. My question is there any other way to do the same. Instead of hacking "navigator.userAgent".

Comment: I think there is no other way since we can only get user agent from UIWebView

Comment: Why is this a hack? The `navigator.userAgent` value is exactly what the webview will use for requests. So it is the most accurate. My only tip is to use the `WKWebView` instead because there is no guarantee that the User Agent of the `UIWebView` is exactly the same as the `WKWebView`.

Comment: Agree.I am wondering Why Apple is doing this. If there is a API to set the customUserAgent , why they can't have a API to get the "defaultUserAgent".